# EditText inside Toast in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toast

I'm creating an application in which I have to display a toast that has a EditText. Is it possible to create an EditText inside a toast ?

Comment: use a dialog for this

Comment: Display a toast that has an EditText... hmmm. Try to rephrase your question. What functionality of "a toast" would you like to have with your EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a prompt user input dialog.

The steps:

Create a prompt dialog layout XML file.
Attach the prompt dialog layout to AlertDialog.Builder.
Attach the AlertDialog.Builder to AlertDialog.

Yout layout/main_activity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrompt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Prompt Dialog" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Create a layout/promtps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private EditText result;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // components from main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrompt);
        result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextResult);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                      });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: rate my que too plz.. :)

Answer (score 2):

A Toast is not a view that can get focus if I remember correctly. What you are referring to is a Dialog.